# Twitter Logout from browser not reflecting in app

Tags: ios, twitter, sttwitter

I have used`STTwitterAPI` to login using either`ACAccountStore` or browser.

Here's a condition thats creating issue for me. When user logs in app using Twitter from browser(default safari), he gets call-backed to app and`STTwitterAPI` object stores the data.

Everything works fine. I can even tweet using that account. But if user switches to browser(default safari) and logs out from Twitter account(which he used while logging) and returns to app to tweet, it is done successfully with old account (associated earlier in browser before logging out), which should not be the case.

I want to ask the user again for logging in as he logged out from browser. I even tried using`verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:errorBlock`: but it returns me user details of old user(the one logged out).

**UPDATE:**

App doesn't redirects user to browser after user is logged in. My concern is if user opens twitter in the browser out of volition, he is shown logged in to an account used while logging in(and that should be the case), but now user decides to either log out from that account or wishes to change account and logs out the account(used during login) from browser.

It gets logs out (which is fine) but when he returns to app, and try to tweet or do anything of twitter account, he should be asked for log in again. For that i used verify credentials. But the access token of previous login is still valid.

So, how to notify app that user has logged out of the browser or switched account. Is there any way to achieve. I'm stuck for at-least a week. Tried every alternative. None of them seems to work in my case. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You!!!

Comment: STTwitter author here. You cannot "logout" from Twitter AP programmatically. There's no endpoint to invalidate an access token. Now in your scenario I don't get why your app would redirect a user to Twitter's web site if the user is already logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the STTwitter framework much. But I can confidently say that TwitterKit by Fabric is much easier to use. I have used it for the scenario of SignUp and SignOut for Twitter in my app and it works flawlessly with the methods provided by it. You can check it out here:

https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/twitter-login

The syntax for login is like this:

```
[[Twitter sharedInstance] logInWithCompletion:^
            (TWTRSession *session, NSError *error) {
  if (session) {
      NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userName]);
  } else {
      NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
  }
}];
```

And for logout you have a `– logOut` method respectively.

Comment: What if user does not uses logout from app but logs out from browser? Can that session be maintained?

Comment: No it does not use the session that is used in the browser. In fact this is a more access token based approach and allows you to have your own Twitter developer app get the access to make the integration tighter.

Comment: I used `-logout` method. But, next time, when I try to login, it does not present login screen.

Comment: Are you calling logInWithCompletion: as mentioned above. Some code/flow would help to debug.